# Azure WebApp Continuous Deployment Does Not Start from Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have an Azure webapp that is configured for continuous deployment.

This webapp is connected to a Container Registry.

It seems that sometimes, when I push an updated tag to the registry, it deploys within a few minutes.

As I write this, I have been waiting for over 30 minutes for the new container to be deployed, and still there is no activity in the webapp log stream.

Why is this happening, and is there any way for me to attain better reliability in the expected redeployment time?